# How to boot USB stick in BIOS mode?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, arch-linux, uefi

I have an UEFI-motherboard - **ASUS P8Z77-MPRO**. It supports CSM(Compatible Support Module). My Win7 is installed in BIOS mode, I've checked it. This because, I must install ArchLinux in the same way(BIOS) to avoid problems with dual-boot system as said in the documentation. But when I'm booting in with my USB it enters in UEFI-mode installation:

[image]

I changed the state of CSM from "**Auto**" to "**Enabled**", marked "**Fastboot**" as "**Disabled**" and so I did with "**SecureBoot**" (Actually, the last one was aslready been marked).

How can I boot with USB not in UEFI mode?

Comment: @Ramhound, do you mean my software like x64, x86 or you're talking exactly about hardware like "i7, GeForce 650" etc.

Comment: You need to name at least your motherboard’s (exact!) make and model. Also, how did you create the bootable USB drive?

Comment: @DanielB, I've used *Rufus* but it didn't work out, then I picked *USBWriter* up and it works. I'm using software from the official guide on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the model of your motherboard (please state your model) you should be able to go into the bios and with your usb device attached, set it as a boot device.  There may be additional UEFI features you need to disable, but without your model it's hard to know.

Comment: It's **ASUS P8Z77-MPRO**

Comment: This should help:  http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/17058-secure-boot-enable-disable-uefi-2.html

Comment: I tried this, and as I've mentioned before it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you'd followed those exact steps...that's actually what did it for me on my Asus board.  I'll let you know if I find anything else

Comment: This is strange...I can't find clear steps to disable uefi, but the odd thing is I had a hard time getting uefi to work!  I'll run some tests on my Asus board in the next day or so and hopefully find something that can help you.

Comment: Your computer has a UEFI firmware, so in a very real sense, you *cannot* disable it. Some computers do permit you to lock the boot mode to always use the CSM, but this ability is far from universal.

Answer (score 0):

For Arch, you should be able to install in EFI/UEFI mode and boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Unlike distributions with more automated installation procedures, [Arch's installation instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_loaders) specify manual selection and installation of the boot manager. Because BIOS-mode booting relies (almost) exclusively on disk-based data, it's possible to fully set up a computer to boot in BIOS mode from an installation medium that's booted in EFI mode, provided the mechanism to do this is not automated in a program that ties boot loader type to the current boot mode.

Comment: Hm, I'm gonna give it a shot right now. I will leave feedback as soon as done.

Comment: I've installed ArchLinux. But got stuck at "os-prober" stage. It doesn't see Windows7 when running 'os-prober' command. I think this is because Win7 was installed in bios mode, when ArchLinux is being installed in EFI (as picture above shows). Am I right that os-prober produce an ignore to me because of different boot mode installation? As we had discussed I can't change the installation mode to not-EFI.

Comment: I've just noticed that version of my BIOS is outdated. I'm gonna update it and see will it work or not..